# Accessing Array Values in a json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this json file that I am appending to the html.

```
"{\"Item1\":[{\"Id\":2,\"Title\":\"Support\",\"Items\":8},{\"Id\":5,\"Title\":\"Datacenter\",\"Items\":5},{\"Id\":3,\"Title\":\"Bogholderiet\",\"Items\":5},{\"Id\":8,\"Title\":\"Helpdesk\",\"Items\":4},{\"Id\":9,\"Title\":\"SLA og VIP\",\"Items\":1},{\"Id\":7,\"Title\":\"Hostmaster\",\"Items\":1}],\"Item2\":[{\"Id\":7,\"FullName\":\"p11\",\"Items\":5},{\"Id\":17,\"FullName\":\"p8\",\"Items\":3},{\"Id\":9,\"FullName\":\"p10\",\"Items\":3},{\"Id\":8,\"FullName\":\"p6\",\"Items\":3},{\"Id\":3,\"FullName\":\"p1\",\"Items\":3},{\"Id\":5,\"FullName\":\"p2\",\"Items\":2},{\"Id\":16,\"FullName\":\"p3\",\"Items\":1},{\"Id\":11,\"FullName\":\"p4\",\"Items\":1}]}"
```

My question is how can I append only the value of "SLA og VIP". Below code I am able to access to array of Item1 and appending it to html.

```
if (key === 'Item1') {
value[key].forEach(function (val) {
var tbl3Row = "<tr " + (parseInt(val.TotalUnresolvedItems) > 3 ? " class='colorgul'" : "") + (parseInt(val.TotalUnresolvedItems) < 4 ? " class='colorgreen'" : "") + ">" + "<td>" + val.Title + "</td>" + "<td>" + val.TotalUnresolvedItems + "</td>" + "</tr>"
table3Rows += tbl3Row;                                   
 })
 }
```

But now I am only trying to access to the Title value"SLA og VIP". This is the formula that i manage to find:

```
parsedData.Item1[4]
```

I just dont know how can I use this inside of this code:

```
if (key === 'Item1') {
value[key].forEach(function (val) {
var tbl3Row = "<tr " + (parseInt(val.TotalUnresolvedItems) > 3 ? " class='colorgul'" : "") + (parseInt(val.TotalUnresolvedItems) < 4 ? " class='colorgreen'" : "") + ">" + "<td>" + val.Title + "</td>" + "<td>" + val.TotalUnresolvedItems + "</td>" + "</tr>"
table3Rows += tbl3Row;                                   
 })
 }
```

Comment: Not clear, be more precise

Comment: `JSON.parse(string).Item1.find(x=>x.Id === 9).Title`

Comment: You currently have 2 objects, each holding an array of Objects, each having `Id`, `Title` or `Fullname` and `Items` properties. What are you calling the `value of "SLA og VIP"`? What are the conditions on which you want to return something? You could use the `id===9` and having a `Title` property. Is this the only possible JSON or are there any cases? What's the logic behind it?

Answer (score 2):

You can [`[].prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) it:

Because it will let you filter to the exact object you need to target. In your case it is

```
{
  "Id": 9,
  "Title": "SLA og VIP",
  "Items": 1
}
```

With this you can get the filtered object's properties like `Id, Title, Items`.

```js
if (key === 'Item1') {
  var obj = value[key].filter(function(item){
     return item.Title === "SLA og VIP"
  })[0];

  // now use obj.Title, output: "SLA og VIP"

  value[key].forEach(function(val) {
    var tbl3Row = "<tr " + (parseInt(val.TotalUnresolvedItems) > 3 ? "...</tr>"
    table3Rows += tbl3Row;
  })
}
```

```js
var json = "{\"Item1\":[{\"Id\":2,\"Title\":\"Support\",\"Items\":8},{\"Id\":5,\"Title\":\"Datacenter\",\"Items\":5},{\"Id\":3,\"Title\":\"Bogholderiet\",\"Items\":5},{\"Id\":8,\"Title\":\"Helpdesk\",\"Items\":4},{\"Id\":9,\"Title\":\"SLA og VIP\",\"Items\":1},{\"Id\":7,\"Title\":\"Hostmaster\",\"Items\":1}],\"Item2\":[{\"Id\":7,\"FullName\":\"p11\",\"Items\":5},{\"Id\":17,\"FullName\":\"p8\",\"Items\":3},{\"Id\":9,\"FullName\":\"p10\",\"Items\":3},{\"Id\":8,\"FullName\":\"p6\",\"Items\":3},{\"Id\":3,\"FullName\":\"p1\",\"Items\":3},{\"Id\":5,\"FullName\":\"p2\",\"Items\":2},{\"Id\":16,\"FullName\":\"p3\",\"Items\":1},{\"Id\":11,\"FullName\":\"p4\",\"Items\":1}]}";

var obj = JSON.parse(json)["Item1"].filter(function(item) {
  return item.Title === "SLA og VIP"
})[0];

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu IMHO you might be right but this answer is just answers the precisely asked question. Although i would add the link and some description.

Comment: I'll delete that comment, since it no longer applies. Thank you.

Comment: @Jai Thank you.I think I have understood that with  .filter(function(item){
     return item.Title === "*"
  })[0];  I am able to filter specific array in an objects.I can also see it in the console when I write console.log(obj);. But when I use value[key].forEach(function(val) {
       var tbl3Row = "<tr " + (parseInt(val.TotalUnresolvedItems) > 3 ? "...</tr>"
    table3Rows += tbl3Row; It appends all the arrays in objects. Do you have any Ide of why.  When I change value[key].forEach(function(val) to value[obj].forEach(function(val) I do get an error says that it is not a valid function.